# How to recover a node in quorum?

Tags: docker, quorum

I have set up a three-node quorum network using docker and if my network crashes, and I only have information of one of the node. Do I want to recover that node using binary? also, the blocks in the new network should be in sync with others. Please guide how is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you’re using docker swarm. The clustering facility within the swarm is maintained by the manager nodes. If for any reason the manager leader becomes unavailable and no enough remaining managers to reach quorum and elect a new manager leader, a quorum is lost and no manager node is able to control the swarm.

In this kind of situations, it may be necessary to re-initialize the swarm and force the creation of a new cluster using the command on the manager leader when it is brought online again:

```
# docker swarm init --force-new-cluster
```

This removes all managers except the manager the command was run from. The good thing is that worker nodes will continue to function normally and the other manager nodes should resume functionality once the swarm has been re-initialized.

Sometimes it might be necessary to remove manager nodes from the swarm and rejoin them to the swarm.

But note that when a node rejoins the swarm, it must join the swarm via a manager node.

You can always monitor the health of manager nodes by querying the docker nodes API in JSON format through the /nodes HTTP endpoint:

```
# docker node inspect manager1 --format "{{ .ManagerStatus.Reachability }}"
# docker node inspect manager1 --format "{{ .Status.State }}"
```

Also, make it a practice to perform automate the backup of docker swarm config directory `/var/lib/docker/swarm` to easily recover from disaster.